# get bounds for gpx track

Tags: android, bounds, gpx

I use android gpx parser library (https://github.com/ticofab/android-gpx-parser) to load a track and display the track on googlemap.

The problem is that I want to see all my track on screen and intend to use

```
mMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(() -> {
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 40);
        mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
    });
```

but for that need to get the bounds for track.

How can I do that? I saw that parser use bounds but I can't figure out how to read them
    https://github.com/ticofab/android-gpx-parser/blob/master/parser/src/main/java/io/ticofab/androidgpxparser/parser/domain/Bounds.java

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this library but I had a look on it and I saw this :

`gpx.getMetadata().getBounds()`

Is that what you want ? If it returns null, you will have to compute the bounds yourself